# Not able to Create a new confluence page as a child of another page

Tags: rest, curl, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Not able to Create a new confluence page as a child of another page with below curl req:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"ancestors":[{"id":456}], "space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":
"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}'
https://wiki/rest/api/content/
```

OS: Windows

Error on using -o with curl:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused

Comment: I don't know the answer but I suspect admin:admin is not a user name and password that your Confluence instance recognizes, hence the "...Connection refused".